# How can I access private property outside that class in Swift?

Tags: swift, getter

Here I have a class and make its properties private to prevent from modifications by accident.

```
class Article {
    private var lineIndex: [Int] = []
    private var text: [String] = []

    ....
}
```

I know I can write a function like `func text(_ index: Int) -> String` to get its value at `index`. But when I call it, `article1.text(2)` would be weird. Because it's less clear to indicate `2` is an index than what an array does like `article1.text[2]`. So can I use `getter` or something else instead, while keeping the clear syntax like `text[2]`. It couldn't be better if you can offer some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of these ways:

- with `private(set)`, which allows editable inside the class:

```swift
class Article {
    private(set) var text: [String] = []
    ...
}
```

- with get only computed property (this is the same like your get function)

```swift
class Article {
    var _text: [String] {
        return text
    }
}
```